# Flask application throws "Exec format error" when run with debug=True

Tags: python, flask

I am following some online tutorials but it doesn't matter what I do I can't make the debug work...can anyone help?

```py
from flask import Flask , request, jsonify

#Init Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


#Run Server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Terminal response..

```
(pyapi) mmestre@DESKTOP-F58KAFC:/mnt/d/Projects/Python/pyapi$ python app.py

 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/home/mmestre/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyapi-U_pT_kGf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/mmestre/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyapi-U_pT_kGf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 988, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/home/mmestre/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyapi-U_pT_kGf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/home/mmestre/.local/share/virtualenvs/pyapi-U_pT_kGf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/mnt/d/Projects/Python/pyapi/app.py'

(pyapi) mmestre@DESKTOP-F58KAFC:/mnt/d/Projects/Python/pyapi$
```

Comment: You have an error on the script: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/mnt/d/Projects/Python/pyapi/app.py'.  So fix it first.

Comment: Don't put the project on a Windows drive.

Comment: I've edited the title to be properly narrow to Flask; it's not something generic to all Python scripts, but specifically about how Flask tries to re-exec a child interpreter (presumably which it can then restart later) on Windows (or on a Windows filesystem -- if this is a UNIX platform but you're saving your project on a Windows disk with no filesystem-level permissions support, well, there's your bug) in debug mode. If you can figure out how to make your script executable (and provide a proper shebang), that may be all you need

Comment: ...what operating system / distro / interpreter / etc *is* this you're running on, anyhow?

Comment: To summarize what I was saying above -- if you fix it to where instead of running `python app.py` you can just run `./app.py`, then your exec format error should go away.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy first of thank you for fixing the title for me! So what you are basically saying is that I should create a Linux partion / Virtual Machine and make my development there, otherwise I will have to endure the pain of restarting my flask server everytime I make a change...is that correct ? At the moment I am using a Windows10 machine with Ubuntu Bash installed from the  Microsoft Store

Comment: You can probably make it work, if the file is stored in a location that tracks UNIX metadata (may or may not be true for `/mnt/*`, but certainly true for `~`), so you can successfully give it `+x` permissions (`chmod +x app.py`), and if it has a valid shebang (first line exactly `#!/usr/bin/env python`, stored with UNIX newlines rather than DOS ones).

Comment: I opted for instaling Ubuntu in the VirtualBox. Thank you!